# How to redirect www.domain.com/example to www.example.com with rewrite?

Tags: apache

I need to redirect http://www.example.com/luis to https://www.luis.com, I have a multisite in http://www.example.com, I used the Apache mod_rewrite. For example I need redirect this:
http://www.example.com/peter to https://www.peter.com 
http://www.example.com/mary to https://www.mary.com
What can I do?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.What have you tried so far? Add a minimal example to your question.

Comment: I have a multisite web, I need redirect with apache mod_rewrite, the alias of the URL to a new domain, for example the alias is: [link](http://www.example.com/peter) to a new domain: [link](https://www.peter.com)